# counter_cache with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have read this isnt possible, and then someone else told me it is. They gave me this code but then had to go, now now my app is broken until I get this working :/

I have a Tag model, and each tag has_many resources :through => resource tags. Each resource also has_many tags.

I need to know the number of resource each tag has (I dont care about the other way around).

The problem is it says unkown key cache_counter

This is my model

Tag.rb

```
  has_many :resource_tags, :dependent => :destroy, :counter_cache => :resource_count
  has_many :resources, :through => :resource_tags
```

Resource.rb

```
  has_many :resource_tags, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :resource_tags
```

My migration:

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|

      t.string  :name
      t.integer :resource_count, :default => 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:counter_cache` option is for `belongs_to` method

in resorce_tag model

```
belongs_to :tag, :counter_cache => :resource_count
```

and i think it is better to name column `resources_count` (plural)

Comment: So I move it into the resource_tag model on :resource or :tag? can you complete your code a bit more? ive tried reading all about this but theres only like 1 line of docuemntation

Comment: so now i have in tag.rb: `has_many :resource_tags, :dependent => :destroy`, in resource_tag.rb i have `belongs_to :tag, :counter_cache => :resources_count` and in resource.rb i have `has_many :resource_tags, :dependent => :destroy`. is that right? i also have `t.integer :resources_count, :default => 0` in my migration